# Scaling HSB colors for export

Tags: export, color

In *Mathematica*, `Hue[h,s,b]` uses HSB colors. However, unlike anything I've ever seen, the `h`, `s`, and `b` have to be between 0 and 1. The trouble is that I am trying to use *Mathematica* to take NSB colors out of an image and pass them to another program, so I need my `h` to be between 0 and 360 (Which is believe is the standard way) and `s` and `b` to be between 0 and 100.

How can I convert *Mathematica's* HSB to what I described?

Comment: Just multiply the MMA values by 360/100/100 to go out, or divide by same to go in, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own converter like so:

```
hue2HSB[color : Hue[h_, s_, b_]] := {360. h, 100. s, 100. b}
```

then

```
Hue[0.55, 0.73, 0.82]
```

[image: hue]

[image: coversion]

The next step would be to export the conversion, but since you don't indicate how you plan to do that, I can't say anything more.

Comment: Thank you! To expand on this, I have a list of lists of colors. How would I apply this function to each of the colors without loops?

Comment: @user40421. Look up [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html); it is the usual function for applying a function to a list of values.